# How to join shipping address to customer collection?

Tags: customer, collection, shipping-address

I want to join default shipping address to customer collection.

**if shipping address is not available  need to join billing address in place of shipping address.**

**For an example**

customer_id email shipping address fields

1. `s@gmail.com`     shipping info
2. `g@gmail.com`     shipping info
3. `k@gmail.com`  billing info

here customer-3 does not contain default shipping address .so i need to replace with default billing address(assumed customer contain default billing address.)

```
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('customer/customer_collection')
    ->addNameToSelect()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('email')
    ->addAttributeToSelect('created_at')                
    ->addAttributeToSelect('group_id')
    ->joinAttribute('shipping_prefix', 'customer_address/prefix', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('shipping_firstname', 'customer_address/firstname', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('shipping_middlename', 'customer_address/middlename', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('shipping_lastname', 'customer_address/lastname', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('shipping_suffix', 'customer_address/suffix', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('shipping_company', 'customer_address/company', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('shipping_street', 'customer_address/street', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('shipping_postcode', 'customer_address/postcode', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('shipping_city', 'customer_address/city', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('shipping_country_id', 'customer_address/country_id', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('shipping_region', 'customer_address/region', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('shipping_telephone', 'customer_address/telephone', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('shipping_fax', 'customer_address/fax', 'default_shipping', null, 'left')
    ->joinAttribute('shipping_vat_id', 'customer_address/vat_id', 'default_shipping', null, 'left');
```

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9387839/mysql-if-not-null-then-display-1-else-display-0

Comment: thanks for your  response.its useful somewhat.but still waiting for magento syntax.

Comment: Sry, I'm from phone... Make getSelect()->columns() unset emails and just add your ifnull column

Comment: address is different eav entity.i'm not able proceed further

Comment: What about joining both addresses and check afterwards which to use?

Answer (score 1):

Writing an SQL query which does what you want is quite complex with magentos collections.

I recommend to implement your own customer class (and I'm NOT talking about a rewrite here!) which encapsulates the whole process.

Join both addresses into the collection, then you have YOUR customer model which contains both. Now you can return either the shipping address if available, the billing address if available or throw an `Exception`.